# Dynamically adding LINK to IMG stag with IMG SRC as link REF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using GetBarley.com for it's wonderful WYSWYG editor... but it's posing a problem for images inside the blog. If someone posts an image, it's size is dictated by the width of the container.

I want to be able to click on that image to see them larger and click through all the images in that particular post. To do this, I need to add a link surrounding the  tag.

What shows up:

```
<img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/image-3.jpg"/>
```

What I need to show up:

```
<a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="set">
<img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/image-3.jpg"/>
```

Note that the href="#" is taking the URL from the img src.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osifer/9Fb3y/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(".image-set img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<a href='" + this.src + "' data-lightbox='set' />");
});
```